# Name of "coordinate representation" of spacetime symmetries

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, terminology, representation-theory

I would like to know the name of the following "natural" representation for symmetry groups that can be realized as spacetime symmetries. The easiest example is for instance the translations group in $D$-dimensions.

Consider a $D$-dimensional flat spacetime. Infinitesimal translations can be written as $x^{\mu}\rightarrow x^\mu+\xi^\mu$, where $\xi^\mu$ is considered small. We can then define an action of $P^\mu$, the generator of the translations, as acting on smooth functions of the $D$ coordinates :
$$
e^{-iP_\mu\xi^\mu}f(x^\mu)=f'(x^\mu)
$$
Where $f'(x^{\mu}{}')=f(x^\mu)$ defines $f'$, and the identity basically states that the function is unchanged under the transformation. Expanding the action of $e^{iP_\mu\xi^\mu}$ for a small parameter and doing a taylor expansion on the right, yields the following expression for the representation of $P_\mu$:

\begin{equation}
P_\mu = -i\partial_\mu
\end{equation}

Thus in this representation the operator is simply a vector field on the flat manifold, acting on functions. Then the natural definition of the Lie Bracket is using the lie Bracket of the vector fields:

$$
 [P_\nu,P_\mu]f(x) = P_\nu(P_\mu(f))-P_\mu(P_\nu(f))=0
$$
Where on the RHS the action is that of the vector field on functions. In this case the Lie bracket is trivial, but for say rotations it will provide the correct relations.

So we can see that this provides a correct representation of translation. In the same way, we can use this method to define representations of the Poincaré group, and even of the conformal group.

My question is if this representation has a standard name. I tried searching for it, but as you might suspect it is hard without knowing the name.

Comment: It's Lagrange's celebrated  [shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), a formal rewriting of the Taylor expansion. ***But*** you've made a sign mistake in your exponent.

Comment: Shift operator is only for the translation, but what is the name of the representation of the full Poincaré group, or conformal group ? I would suppose there is a name denoting the representations obtained by the method I outlined in my post.

As for the sign in the exponent, I followed the physicist conventions, which indeed differ from the mathematics convention by a sign and an $i$, usually.

Comment: Whatever you followed, your exponent boils down to $-\xi^\mu\partial_\mu$, whose exponential  translates *x* by *-ξ*, in whatever convention. All Lie exponentiations of said generators are basically sophisticated generalizations of the shift operator. Experiment with logarithmic variables!

Comment: Yes, the translation by $-\xi$ is correct, as in my definition the operator acts "actively" on the functions. So as we change the coordinates by $+\xi$, it is natural that the associated function translated by $-\xi$. This is the standard POV in QFT books, although the "passive" POV is equivalent.